Firefox shows wrong layout with Shiny for Python 1.0.0
The new Shiny for Python 1.0.0 seems to be incompatible with Firefox. I made this dummy app:
from shiny import App, render, ui, reactive
from pathlib import Path


app_ui = ui.page_fillable(
    ui.panel_title(
        ui.row(
        ui.column(6, ui.h1("title1")),
        ui.column(6, ui.h1("title2"))
        )
    ),
    ui.layout_sidebar(
        ui.sidebar(
            ui.input_text("input_text1", "input_text1", value=""),
            ui.input_text("input_text2", "input_text2", value=""),
            ui.input_text("input_text3", "input_text3", value=""),
            ui.input_text("input_text4", "input_text4", value=""),
            ui.input_text("input_text5", "input_text5", value=""),

            ui.input_selectize("input_selectize1", "input_selectize1", choices=["1", "2"]),
            ui.input_numeric("input_numeric1", "input_numeric1", value=4),
            ui.input_numeric("input_numeric2", "input_numeric2", value=8),
            ui.input_numeric("input_numeric3", "input_numeric3", value=20),
            ui.input_selectize("input_selectize2", "input_selectize2", choices=["3", "4", "5"]),
            ui.input_numeric("input_numeric4", "input_numeric4", value=1),
            ui.input_numeric("input_numeric5", "input_numeric5", value=1),
            ui.input_switch("input_switch1", "input_switch1", value=False),
            ui.input_switch("input_switch2", "input_switch2", value=False),
            ui.input_switch("input_switch3", "input_switch3", value=False),
            ui.input_action_button("input_action_button1", "input_action_button1"),
            ui.input_action_button("input_action_button2", "input_action_button2", disabled=True),
            width="350px"
        ),
        ui.layout_columns(
            ui.card(
                ui.card_header("card_header1"),
                ui.output_data_frame("card1"),
                full_screen=True
            ),
            ui.card(
                ui.card_header("card_header2"),
                ui.output_data_frame("card2"),
                full_screen=True
            ),
            col_widths=[12, 12]
        )
    )
)


def server(input, output, session):

    @reactive.event(input.input_action_button1)
    def reactive_function1():
        pass

    @output
    @render.data_frame
    def card1():
        return reactive_function1()

    @output
    @render.data_frame
    def card2():
        pass

    @reactive.effect
    @reactive.event(input.write_guides)
    def reactive_function2():
        return reactive_function1()

src_dir = Path(__file__).parent / "src"
app = App(app_ui, server, static_assets=src_dir)

Then I started it and opened it with Safari (left) and Firefox (right).
With Shiny for Python 0.10.2 both browsers seem fine:

But as soon as I switch to Shiny for Python 1.0.0, Firefox fails, but Safari is still able to display:

Not sure, if this is of any use, but I can "expand" the sidebar in Firefox leading to this:

Any ideas, what's wrong? Can I fix this in my code or does this need to be fixed by the devs?
EDIT: This is a cross-post from GitHub

You should mention cross-posts. Also this is not reproducible for me using Firefox 128.0.3.

Mentioned the cross-post. Didn't know there's a rule for that. I am also on Firefox 128.0.3. How do you install shiny for python 1.0.0? I am using conda in this case. Maybe I'll try PyPI. Did you use my exact code?

Ha, seems to be the solution was as easy as to delete the Firefox cache and website settings. Didn't think of that :D.

Thank you! There is no rule concerning cross-posts, but it could prevent others to spend time on investigating a problem which was in the meantime maybe solved somewhere else.

I had to delete the Firefox cache and website setting and now it's working.

Sorry, forgot about that.
